# jQuery problem with :checked siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery function that changes the subtotal when a radio button is clicked. There will be 3+ radio buttons - each with a different price value that will add onto the existing subtotal.

I **only** want the subtotal to be updated if there are no existing radio buttons selected (this set of radio buttons - with the same `name` attribute).  This is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="45" name="timescale" onclick="changePrice(this)">
```

jQuery:

```
function changePrice(t){
  v = parseInt($(t).val());
  s = $("#subtotal");      
  x = parseInt(s.text());
  if($(t).siblings("input").is(":checked")){
    s.text(x);
  } else {
    s.text(x + v);
  }
}
```

I want the if statement to check if the radio button's siblings are selected. If they are: only replace the subtotal `s.html()` with its current value. If they aren't: replace the `s.html()` with the updated value (which is the current value + the radio button's value). But at the moment every click updates the subtotal - even if other radio buttons are already selected. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the html containing the whole set of your radio buttons? Or are you only working with one at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
The problem is that the moment of the `change` event, there's already a checked radio (you don't know previous state). You could store this state in an auxiliar var, like this:

```
var $checked; //This is the aux var that saves previous state
$(document).ready(function(){
   $checked = $(":radio[name='timescale']:checked");
});

function changePrice(t){
  v = parseInt($(t).val());
  s = $("#subtotal");      
  x = parseInt(s.text());  
  if($checked.size() > 0){
    s.text(x);
  } else {
    s.text(x + v);
  }
  $checked = $(this);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers